# Create an instance of Image from a path in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

Lets say for example we have the path `/assets/no-thumbnail.png`, how can load that to the `Image` class in SilverStripe? Is there a way I can do this?

The reason I ask is because I want the methods which are available in the `Image` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it is pretty straight forward for files that exist in the `/assets` folder. While it can likely be achieved for files in other locations, the method I will describe will treat the file no differently from any other file you upload via the CMS.

Firstly, we need to make sure there is a DB record for this image. Fortunately, it can be as easy as calling [`Filesystem::sync()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Filesystem.html#_sync) if you need to do this programmatically. If not, there is a "Sync" button in the Files tab in the CMS.

Once that is done, you can simply call `File::get()->filter('Name', 'no-thumbnail.png')->first()` (or even just [`File::find('no-thumbnail.png')`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-File.html#_find)) to get your "proper" `Image` object, allowing you to call any of the of the [`Image` class's instance methods](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Image.html).

Comment: This worked perfactly, I used File::find() since code looks much cleaner with it. Thank you so much.